# How do you import an air-gapped created multisig wallet from Coldcard to Electrum?

Tags: electrum, coldcard

I went through the process of creating a 3/5 multisig with coldcard, air gapped. I generated an electrum wallet file, but now I'm struggling to figure out how I use electrum to import the multisig wallet (as a watch-only).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I do not own coldcard devices but [this tutorial](https://www.veriphi.io/en/blog/coldcard-multisig-tutorial) goes through the whole process of creating a multisig wallet with Electrum.

When you open Electrum for the first time it will ask you to select a wallet file (or create a new wallet). Just select the electrum wallet file you previously created on the microSD card. As stated in the linked tutorial, the electrum file should be named something like `el-CC-M-of-N.json`.

This will import your multisig wallet i.e. all cosigner xpubs, allowing you to view transactions, derive addresses and create transactions for signing.